# ¿Cómo buscar registros que coincidan con los datos de un JSON mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, base-de-datos, mariadb

Soy nuevo con el manejo de búsquedas *JSON* en *MySQL* y no logro obtener resultados de la consulta...

Tengo una tabla llamada `shipping_services` con la siguiente estructura (`sird` es la llave primaria):

```
sird int(11) NOT NULL
tarifas json NOT NULL
```

Esta sería más o menos la estructura de un registro del *JSON* `tarifas`:

```
{"1": {"cf": {"configs": ["3", "400", "3000", "0"], "wSentences": [["1", "1", "1", "1", "1000"], ["3", "2", "2", "1", "7000"]]}, "fr": ["29", "33"], "to": ["30", "62"], "tp": "2"}}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es encontrar todos los registros en donde dentro de "tarifas", **por ejemplo:** `to` sea `62` y al mismo tiempo `fr` sea `29`.

Si se puede condicionar la consulta a ambos criterios a la vez (`to` y `fr`), sería genial. Si no se puede, con que solo se pueda encontrar `to` también me sirve.

Intenté con: (primero quería probar si podía conseguir resultados en los que coincidiera `to`)

```
SELECT * FROM shipping_services WHERE JSON_CONTAINS('tarifas', '62', '$.to')
```

```
SELECT * FROM shipping_services WHERE JSON_EXTRACT('tarifas' , '$.to')=62
```

y con `json_search`, pero no logro que me devuelva algún resultado.

En el path probé poniendo `$.to`, `$.to[*]`, `$[*].to`, `$[*].to[*]`, pero no se si va por ahí el problema.

Tampoco sé si el problema está en la consulta, si el *path* que indiqué es incorrecto, el problema es el *JSON*, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo visto el formato JSON tiene un nivel mas al que se debe acceder (con indice `"1"`)

```
{
 "1": {
  "cf": {
   "configs": [
    "3",
    "400",
    "3000",
    "0"
   ],
   "wSentences": [
    [
     "1",
     "1",
     "1",
     "1",
     "1000"
    ],
    [
     "3",
     "2",
     "2",
     "1",
     "7000"
    ]
   ]
  },
  "fr": [
   "29",
   "33"
  ],
  "to": [
   "30",
   "62"
  ],
  "tp": "2"
 }
}
```

Por lo que la ruta de acceso seria `$.1.to`. Ademas, puedes unir varias condiciones usando `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM shipping_services WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tarifas, '62', '$.1.to') and JSON_CONTAINS(tarifas, '29', '$.1.fr');
```

Si el indice de primer nivel no es fijo (`"1"`) puedes considerar usar un comodin (`*`)

```
SELECT * FROM shipping_services WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tarifas, '62', '$.*.to') and JSON_CONTAINS(tarifas, '29', '$.*.fr');
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax

Comment: La consulta no devuelve resultados (incluso utilizando solo 1 condición en la consulta) Esto es en lo que probé con MariaDB.

Hice el mismo ejercicio con MySQL y devuelve "#3143 - Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3."

Adicionalmente, puede haber más de 1 índice en el mismo json (con la misma estructura que tiene el índice 1 del ejemplo), ¿cómo quedaría el path en ese caso?

Como acotación, tuve que quitarle las comillas a tarifas, de lo contrario arroja "Warning: #4038 Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_contains' at position 1"

Comment: Corregi las comillas en `tarifas`. Ademas agregue el caso cuando hay mas de un indice. Debes confirmar ademas si la estructura base es un JSON object o JSON array, en este ultimo caso se debe usar el operador `[]` para acceder al indice `$[1].to`

Comment: Logré solucionarlo utilizando `SELECT * FROM shipping_services WHERE JSON_SEARCH(tarifas, 'all', "62", NULL, '$.*.to') is not null`. Resulta que no se puede utilizar `*` en `JSON_CONTAINS`.